# Retrieve data from 2 tables with username instead of id

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables

```
users
student_id username
         1 Alex
         2 Tom
         3 Max

answers
exercise_done student_id
            4          1
            5          1 
            6          2
```

In the ‘users’ table it lists the username with the corresponding ID.
What I’m trying to do is display al of the data from the table ‘answers’ in php but in the column student_id, I would like to display the username. I know how to display the table ‘answers’, but I would like to show in the column student_id, the name of the user. To display the table ‘answers’ this is what I have:

```
SELECT exercise_done, student_id from answers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call this a jointure :

```
SELECT A.exercise_done, U.student_id, U.username
FROM answers AS A
JOIN users AS U
    ON U.student_id = A.student_id
```

This is why in a relationnal model you need unique to have a foreign keys in tables. With them you can do jointure like this.

There are multiples jointure types but this one is good for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a join:

```sql
SELECT exercise_done, username
FROM   answers a
JOIN   users u ON a.student_id = u.student_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using inner join.

```
select username, exercise_done from users u JOIN answers a ON u.student_id=a.student_id;
```